# What is the difference between struct and dict?

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

These two terms are used a lot in this [documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/%40struct-and-%40dict-Annotations). The notion of `struct` is easy to understand i.e object whose properties are fixed but then we have `dict` which can have any number of properties so, how its different from the normal `Object`? why need a separate type for this feature?

Comment: `@struct` and `@dict` are just annotations that tell the compiler how the object is going to be used. That's explained in the documentation you linked to. Not sure I understand your issue...

Comment: @FelixKling as I told `struct` has a valid reason to be separate type but in javascript we already have implicit notion on `dict` as an Object, why we need to create a separate type for that? in fact we can use plain Object as a dict.

Comment: That seems to mean that every object not explicitly annotated as @struct could only be accessed using bracket notation, i.e. how to use the object would be implicitly restricted. Explicit seems better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key difference is given on that [documentation page](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/%40struct-and-%40dict-Annotations)

> By using @struct, you know that the compiler will rename all properties safely, because you can't use bracket access. By using @dict, you know that the properties will have the same name after compilation.

(A key thing to understand about closure compiler is that [properties accessed with bracket notation are not renamed](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations#implications-of-global-variable-function-and-property-renaming)).

Using closure compiler restricts your usage of JavaScript, in the ways that YOU specify. You are telling the compiler to warn you when you write code that breaks the restrictions that you put in place with annotations like `@struct` and `@dict`.

The `@dict` is indeed "like a normal `Object`" as you say.  By using `@dict` you are telling the compiler that you are going to be adding properties to an object and you don't want those properties renamed to minimal names.

In contrast `@struct` is typically used for class where you don't care what the compiler renames properties to be.  You also don't expect to ever add a property to such an object, so it should be an error if you do.

BTW, the examples on that [page about struct and dict](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/%40struct-and-%40dict-Annotations) are a bit difficult to understand in my opinion, so if you are still confused about anything on that page feel free to ask more.